# Apache Guacamole Multi-factor Authentication

Tags: apache-http-server, authentication, google-authenticator, token, guacamole

I installed Apache Guacamole 1.0.0 on Ubuntu machine.
I am able to navigate to login page. I log in using '**guacadmin**/**guacadmin**' credentials. 
I can get in, but right after i enter my credentials and hit on Login button, i get to a screen where i have a **QR Code**; asks me to scan the code and enter the 6-digit-authentication code. 
I scanned the QR Code with '**Google Authenticator**' and got my 6-digit code. When i enter on Guacamole, says 'Verification Failed'

can you guys help me how to solve this. I'm stuck!!!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I got this to not prompt for MFA by deleting /etc/guacamole/extensions/guacamole-auth-totp-1.0.0.jar